# Collision analysis with line diameter in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, spatial-analyst, intersection, dimensions

I have some lines representing pipes. They have Z value in the attribute. I need to check if they collide with each other. So I want to know where they intersect/collide in height.

I was wondering if it is possible to do this in QGIS somehow. I now the specified value of the diameter ex 200. Is it possible to make an analysis with the height and the diameter to see where they collide

Comment: We would need a bit more information about how your data is structured - best provide sample data and post a screenshot